# Using Spring JdbcTemplate to extract one string

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

Can't seem to find a way to get one string from table using JdbcTemplate query.
This is the table my sql returns:

```
ID | STREET_NAME
------------------------
1  | Elm street
```

Now how am I supposed to get the value of STREET_NAME. SQL always returns one row, so no need to worry about returning more than one row.

For some background info:
[INNER JOIN and COUNT in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266384/inner-join-and-count-in-the-same-query)

Using Tony Stark answer to get my table.

But how can I extract "Elm street" from it using JdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It would help a lot to know what your SQL query looks like, but assuming it's something like `SELECT STREET_NAME FROM table WHERE ID=1;`

CODE:

```
public String getStreetNameById(int id) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "SELECT STREET_NAME FROM table WHERE ID=?";

    String streetName = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            sql, new Object[] { id }, String.class);

    return streetName;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code for sure. How does it know what column do you need to get back? It said: "Incorrect column count: expected 1, actual 2"

Comment: this is deprecated I am reading, what is the updated solution? queryForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Class<T>)' is deprecated

Comment: you can use now:  ```queryForObject(sql, String.class, id)```

Answer (score 15):

The class [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class-) implements [`JdbcOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html).

If you look at the [`queryForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class-) javadocs in `JdbcOperations` it states:

> **Deprecated**. as of 5.3, in favor of [queryForObject(String, Class, Object...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-)

Basically, they have changed the method signature to get rid of `Object[]` arguments in the method signatures in favor of varargs. Please, see the relevant [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25272).

You can rewrite answer of @jlewkovich with the new method signature like this:

```java
public String getStreetNameById(int id) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "SELECT STREET_NAME FROM table WHERE ID=?";

    String streetName = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            sql, String.class, id);

    return streetName;
}
```

Comment: How to get multiple column in select statement.

Comment: @VedPrakash It is the same as explained, but you need to use some kind of row mapping mechanism to build your object. Please, see for instance [this related article](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/) for a great couple of examples. I hope it helps.

Comment: String checkDuplicateFileQry = "select job_id, site_level_batch_id from toplevel_bulk_status where file_checksum ='" + checksum
    + "'";
  logger.log(INFO, "checkDuplicateFileQry :: " + checkDuplicateFileQry);
  List<String> fileIdList = new ArrayList<>();
  try {
   List<Map<String, Object>> uploadedFileId = ((ConnectionFactoryPostgresReaderImpl) cfPostgresReaderImpl).getConnection()
     .queryForList(checkDuplicateFileQry, new Object[] {checksum});

Comment: I don't want to use row mapper, I'm using above code but getting error message :  The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0. but when i ran this query in my db console it's return row

Comment: issue in my query, missing ? mark in where condition.

Comment: Hi @VedPrakash. Yes, certainly it can be the cause of the error. Sorry, but I think there is something missing on your code. I assume you are using `jdbcTemplate.queryForList`. Please, if that assumption is correct, you could use for instance the example 2.4 in the link I mentioned previously, and build your list as you need to. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jdbcTemplate, Issue resolved,  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I didn't do this.

Comment: @OnicTeam Sorry, I wasn't aware that you were mentioned by my comment; it was not my intention to mention you, I was just trying to ask the person who downvoted the answer yesterday if he/she could provide any reason of the downvote. Sorry again, and thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get only one column "string" from your table (or any query with joins), you have to say the name of the column.

Using **SELECT * FROM TABLE** is a very-very bad practice by the way. I bet you did this.

@JLewkovich modified code:

```
public String getStreetNameById(int id) {
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  String sql = "SELECT STREET_NAME FROM table WHERE ID=?";

  String streetName = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        sql, new Object[] { id }, String.class);

  return streetName;
}
```

But what if there is 0 or more than one result?
Think about it!

But to getting a sequence value (in Oracle), this should work.

```
public Long getSequence() {
  Long seq;
  String sql = "select SEQ_XY.NEXTVAL from dual";
  seq = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {}, Long.class);
  return seq;
}
```

Comment: If you use queryforobject and you get back zero row. It will throw a EmptyResultDataAccessException. It is recommended to use the query method instead so that you can handle it properly.

Comment: this is deprecated I am reading, what is the updated solution? queryForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Class<T>)' is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

As per latest specification [queryForObject](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class-) with below syntax is now **deprecated**

```
<T> T   queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, Class<T> requiredType)
```

New method uses [varargs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-).

```
<T> T   queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType, Object... args)
```

**Updated Solution:** We have to replace the class type with Object args and vice-versa.

Sql Query:    `SELECT STREET_NAME FROM table WHERE ID=1;`

```
public String getStreetNameById(int id) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "SELECT STREET_NAME FROM table WHERE ID=?";

    String streetName = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            sql, String.class, new Object[] { id });

    return streetName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this way:

```
String result = DataAccessUtils.singleResult(
    jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
        "SELECT street_name FROM table WHERE id = :id",
        Collections.singletonMap("id", id),
        String.class
    )
)
```

**queryForList** is used instead of **queryForObject** for handling empty results. **queryForObject** throws EmptyResultDataAccessException for empty results. Often it is not desired behavior.

**DataAccessUtils.singleResult** + **queryForList**:

- returns null for empty result
- returns single result if exactly 1 row found
- throws exception if more then 1 rows found. Should not happen for primary key / unique index search

[DataAccessUtils.singleResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/support/DataAccessUtils.html#singleResult-java.util.Collection-)